# jQuery - dynamic content click event not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, click

I am having an issue with getting a click event to work on some dynamic content.

It is a little more complicated than this but pretty much I have a select2 input which when the user types a search term will do an ajax request and add the returned data to a table.

I have some extra code which should run when the td element of this content is clicked. If there is only a small amount of ajax data returned then the click event will execute correctly and target the correct element, however, if there is a large amount of data added to the table and I have to scroll down the page and then click the td element the event will not execute, instead it will target the tbody element instead.

I am using code similar to this:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    var target = $( e.target );

    if( target.is( "#myId table tr td" ) ) {
        console.log("td element has been clicked!");
    }

});
```

I have also tried the following:

```
 $( document ).on( 'click', '#myId table tr td', function(e) {
    console.log( "td element has been clicked!" );
 });
```

However, the results were the same as with the first section of code.

Is there any reason why scrolling and clicking a dynamically created element will target the tbody instead of the td element?

---

Results of console.log the target and the HTML structure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can you tell that the tbody element is getting the 'click' event?

Comment: Also, can you add an example of what you are seeing in your dynamic content? (ie the table html structure)

Comment: To see which element was getting the click event I was using console.log on the "target" variable on the first section of code. I have added a picture of what the log would look like for each instance. I have also put an image of the HTML of the table, along with an expanded tr to see the td content.

Answer (score 0):

Always write **functions** to access dynamically created pages.
If you write the code in `$(document).bla()`,
your javascript code might have loaded even before the dynamic page loads.

> Simply place an onclick event handler `<td onclick='callFunction()'>` on the td, to call on the function.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- make sure that if you do `$("#myId table tr td").length` it is returning the # of rows you expect
- make sure this wrapped around a `document.ready` handler.

You could also try a more scoped example:

```
$( "#myId" ).on( "click", "td", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```